# Android expandable listview removing group item messes up view

Tags: android, expandablelistview

When i try to remove a group from the expandable listview, the adapter creates a duplicate view inside the upper group item.

So i have the following **expandable listview** containing 3 groups and every group has one child:
[image: Explanation lsitview]

When i try to remove the group item called "**Toegevoegd**" indicated by the following screenshot:
[image]

The listview removes the group which is exactly what i want, but the problem is that the previous group item called "andere" creates a **duplicate**
[image]

Following code snippet shows the remove process:

```
                for (Iterator<Header> headerIterator = articleList.iterator(); headerIterator.hasNext(); ) {
                Header header = headerIterator.next();
                if (header.getType().equals(selectedPickingLine.getType())) {
                    ArrayList<PickingLine> pickingLines = header.getPickingLineList();
                    for (Iterator<PickingLine> pickingLineIterator = pickingLines.iterator(); pickingLineIterator.hasNext(); ) {
                        PickingLine pickingLine = pickingLineIterator.next();
                        if (pickingLine.getPickingLineNr() == selectedPickingLine.getPickingLineNr()) {
                            if (selectedPickingLine.getAmount() == 0) {
                                articleRemoved = true;
                                if (pickingLines.size() == 1) {
                                    headerIterator.remove();
                                } else {
                                    pickingLineIterator.remove();
                                }
                            } else {
                                pickingLines.set(pickingLines.indexOf(pickingLine), selectedPickingLine);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

The **HeaderIterator** controls the group view and the **pickingLineIterator** controls the children for every group item.

I pass the underlying arraylist "articleList" to the adapter when initializing the adapter:

```
    public OrderlinesHeaderAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<Header> articleList) {
    this.articleList = articleList;
    this.activity = activity;
}
```

Why does the adapter create a duplicate entry ?
I debugged the application and the underlying arraylist doesn't contain any duplicates...

Answer (score 2):

The solution for me was to first collapse the group I was removing.

```
yourListView.collapse(groupPosition);
yourListViewDataList.remove(groupPosition);
yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```